# How to link two objects of different classes?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I want to build a REST API for a library (endpoints are customers and invoices). One of the features is to add an invoice (PUT request with customer id). Firstly I have to check if the passed customer id (via PUT in the URL) exists, this means to check the customerMap and look after the id under discussion. The problem is that customerMap is a HashMap in the class clientService (and not in the class invoiceService) (the Map is used instead of a database). How can I reach the data stored in the map? Hereby the relevant part of the code:

client

```
public class client {

private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

private final long id;

public client() {
    this.id = counter.getAndIncrement();
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

clientService

```
public class clientService {
public Map<Long, client> clientMap = new HashMap<>();

public client put(client g) {
    clientMap.put(g.getId(), g);
    return g;
}

public Collection<client> getAll() {
    return clientMap.values();
}
}
```

invoice

```
invoice  {

private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

private final long id;
private client client;

public invoice() {
    this.id = counter.getAndIncrement();
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

invoiceService

```
public class invoiceService {
private Map<Long, invoice> invoiceMap = new HashMap<>();

public Rechnung createinvoice(invoice g, long id) {

    if(<!--client exists-->)
    invoicegMap.put(g.getId(), g);
    return g;
}}
```

Comment: Linking the two classes would probably result in bad design. When a new invoice is being created, why don't you query the `clientService` to check if the client exists? It's the `clientService` responsibility to have information about the clients and it's not a responsibility of the `invoiceService`, so implementing such check inside the `invoiceService` class wouldn't be preferable.

Comment: Please always start class names with an uppercase character

Answer (score 0):

First add a method to your ClientService to look up a client by id :

```
public Client getClientById(Long clientId) {
   return clientMap.get(clientId);
}
```

Then inject your ClientService in to your Invoice Service ;

```
public class invoiceService {
private Map<Long, invoice> invoiceMap = new HashMap<>();
private ClientService clientService; // provide a getter or a constructor argument for the service

public Rechnung createinvoice(invoice g, long id) {

    if(clientService.getClientById(id) != null) {
      invoicegMap.put(g.getId(), g);
}
    return g;
}}
```